# How to specify headers-expression in Spring Cloud Data Flow processor "http-request"?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-expression-language

We are trying to pass the basic authentication header when using the SCDF prebuilt processor "*http-request*" to call an external service. From my understanding, the message http headers are not automatically carried over in making the call, we need to populate the "*headers-expression*" property instead. The following is the the call processor step of the stream definition:

```
http-request --body-expression=payload
--url-expression='headers.reportURL' --http-method-expression='headers.httpMethod' --headers-expression='headers.Authorization'
```

We already had set the message header "*Authorization*" as "*Basic <base64encoded("user:password")>*" in previous step so "*headers.Authorization*" has the correct Basic Authentication header value when the message arrives to "*http-request*" processor. However, this doesn't work, the stream log has the following error:

*org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1001E: Type conversion problem, cannot convert from java.lang.String to java.util.Map     at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:75)    at org.springframework.expression.common.ExpressionUtils.convertTypedValue(ExpressionUtils.java:57)*

From the error message, it appears we need to pass a map? Something like "*Authorization : headers.Authorization*"? (The stream wasn't even deployed successfully by coding this way). We don't want to hard-code the "*headers.Authorization*" as the literal Basic Auth base64 string. Also how to specify more than one header (like adding "*content-type*") in the "*headers-expression*"? We have searched the SCDF documentation and online but can't seem to find an example of how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say that you have already set those headers upfront, consider just that expression like this: `--headers-expression='headers'. The` headers`property of the`Message`is a`Map` by itself.

If that still doesn't fit your requirements, consider to use an `in-line map` syntax for SpEL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-inline-maps

Comment: It works by just using 'headers'. Thanks a lot, Artem!